# Process List<string,string> in batches of 1000 using Semaphore

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, semaphore, parallel.foreach

I have 300 000 sale orders which needs to send in batches of either 200 or 1000/batch to a RestAPI call and with multi threading and using `Semaphore` and limit `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8`(better be number of CPU cores). Response of each batch orders needs to add into a generic list. Please suggest any possibility to get list of API response for all 300k orders.

```
  Parallel.ForEach(
    totalSalesOrdersList.Batch(1000),
    new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 /* better be number of CPU cores */ },
    batchOfSalesOrders => {
        DoMyProcessing(batchOfSalesOrders);
    });


 public static class LinqExtensions
 {
   public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> Batch<TSource>(
          this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int size)
   {
    TSource[] bucket = null;
    var count = 0;

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (bucket == null)
            bucket = new TSource[size];

        bucket[count++] = item;
        if (count != size)
            continue;

        yield return bucket;

        bucket = null;
        count = 0;
    }

    if (bucket != null && count > 0)
        yield return bucket.Take(count);
   }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you stack responses in a shared list after you get them from `DoMyProcessing(batchOfSalesOrders)`?

Answer (score 2):

Making a large number of concurrent remote API calls should be performed carefully as you might exhaust the connection pool. I suggest an approach with a `SemaphoreSlim` to perform the throttling and a `Channel` to consume the responses in a thread safe way.

```cs
var batches = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000);
var responseCh = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();
var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(10);

var requestTasks = batches.Select(async batch =>
{
    await throttler.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        var result = await MakeHttpRequestAsync(batch);
        await responseCh.Writer.WriteAsync(result);   
    }
    finally
    {
        throttler.Release();
    }
}).ToArray();

var requestProcessing = Task.Run(async () =>
{                
    await Task.WhenAll(requestTasks);
    responseCh.Writer.Complete();
});

var responseProcessing = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await foreach (var res in responseCh.Reader.ReadAllAsync())
        Console.WriteLine(res); // or store in a data structure
});

await Task.WhenAll(requestProcessing, responseProcessing);
```

We throttle the requests by not allowing more than 10 at a time. We run them concurrently and at the time of arrival, we write the response to the channel. We process the responses on a separate thread by reading them from the channel. Both the request and response processing happen concurrently so we asynchronously wait for both of them to complete.

Note that the `IAsyncEnumerable` interface (`await foreach`) is available in C# 8 and the channels ship with .NET Core 3.1 SDK or you can find them on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Channels/).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Parallel LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq) ([`AsParallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asparallel) method), and control the concurrency with the method [`WithDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.withdegreeofparallelism):

```
var result = Partitioner
    .Create(totalSalesOrdersList.Batch(1000), EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering)
    .AsParallel()
    .AsOrdered()
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(8)
    .Select(batch => DoMyProcessing(batch))
    .SelectMany(batch => batch)
    .ToList();
```

Generally though it is not recommended to [control the concurrency of I/O-bound operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806951/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-concurrent-async-i-o-operations) with PLINQ or the `Parallel` class. Currently the most "professional" way to do it is by using the [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library.

Comment: how can i get with TPL and using with Semaphore for the above?

Comment: You would use a [`BatchBlock<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.batchblock-1) to organize the items in batches, and then you would link it to a [`TransformBlock<T1,T2>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.transformblock-2) to process the batches. The TPL Dataflow library has some learning curve. You can't use it effectively without studying it for a day or two.